# Simplifying this expression involving binomial coefficients.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

\begin{align*} f(y) &=\left(\frac\delta{1-\delta}\right)^y(1-p)^n\sum_{u=0}^{n-y}\binom{u+y}y\binom n{u+y}\alpha^{u+y}\\ &=\left(\frac\delta{1-\delta}\right)^y(1-p)^n\alpha^y\sum_{u=0}^{n-y}\binom{n-y}u\binom ny\alpha^u\\ &=\left(\frac\delta{1-\delta}\right)^y(1-p)^n\alpha^y\binom ny \sum_{u=0}^{n-y}\binom{n-y}u a^u\\ &=\left(\frac\delta{1-\delta}\right)^y(1-p)^n\alpha^y\binom ny (1+\alpha)^{n-y} \end{align*} How do I get from the 1st step to 2nd? In particular how do I get $$ \left( \begin{array}{c} u+y \\ y \end{array} \right) \left( \begin{array}{c} n \\ u+y \end{array} \right) = \left( \begin{array}{c} n-y \\ u \end{array} \right) \left( \begin{array}{c} n \\ y \end{array} \right) $$ And it will be nice to know whats the intuition to do such a simplification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that hard. 
$$\binom{u+y}{y}\binom{n}{u+y} = \frac{(u+y)!n!}{y!u!(u+y)!(n-u-y)!} =\frac{n!}{y!u!(n-u-y)!} =\\= \frac{n!}{y!(n-y)!}\frac{(n-y)!}{u!(n-u-y)!} = \binom{n}{y}\binom{n-y}{u}$$

Comment: How do u get: $\frac{n!}{y!u!(n-u-y)!} =\\= \frac{n!}{y!(n-y)!}\frac{(n-y)!}{u!(n-u-y)!}$

Comment: One can multiply $(n-y)!$ on each side to get the needed form

Comment: Consider $\frac{(n-y)!}{(n-y)!} = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
u+y \\
y
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
n \\
u+y
\end{array}
\right)
= \frac{(u+y)!}{u!y!} \cdot\frac{n!}{(u+y)!(n-u-y)!}= \frac{(n-y)!}{u!(n-y-u)!} \cdot\frac{n!}{y!(n-y)!}=
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
n-y \\
u
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
n \\
y
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: How do u get $\frac{(n+y)!}{u!y!} \cdot\frac{n!}{(u+y)!(n-u-y)!}= \frac{(n-y)!}{u!(n-y-u)!} \cdot\frac{n!}{y!(n-y)!}$?

Comment: There was a typo. I corrected it.

Comment: Oh the think I dont understand is how to split the numerator like that? It probably come from the denominator, but which part?

Comment: I simply multiplied the numerator and the denominator by $(n-y)!$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a particular version of the fairly well-known *trinomial revision identity* (see, e.g., the third page of [this](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masgax/week3.pdf)).
$${n\choose m}{m\choose k}={n\choose k}{n-k\choose m-k}$$
In your case, take $k=y$ and $m=u+y$.

Answer (score 0):

To choose from a set of $n$ elements two disjoint subsets $Y$ of $y$ elements and $U$ of $u$ elements, either select $u+y$ elements first to become $U\cup Y$, and then among those select $y$ elements to become $Y$ (the left hand side), or alternatively choose $y$ elements to become $Y$ first, and among the $n-y$ remaining elements choose $u$ to become $U$ (the right hand side).